# Arabic page numbers appearing when I want Roman

Tags: page-numbering

I am currently writing my MSc thesis and I am having a problem with roman and arabic page numbering. I would like the *Contents*, *List of Figures* and *List of Tables* all to have roman page numbers. I would then like the arabic numbers to start at the *Introduction*. I have included my code below.

At the moment I am strangely seeing roman page numbers on the *Contents* and *List of Figures*, but the arabic numbers are starting on the *List of Tables* page instead of the *Introduction* page! I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am using the `book` class.

Note - In case anyone is wondering, I am using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` to prevent List of Figures and List of Tables from being numbered as chapters.

```
% Contents %
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

% List of Figures %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{List of Figures}

% List of Tables %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} 
\chapter{List of Tables}

% Introduction %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some considerations for your code:

- You don't need to repeatedly set `secnumdepth`. Once is sufficient, as it will hold from there onward;
- `\pagenumbering` resets the `page` counter to 1, so you don't have to do it explicitly;
- Most (if not all) document classes offer `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` just like `\tableofcontents`, so use them. By default, the List of Figures and Tables will not show up in the ToC.
- Issue `\cleardoublepage` (or just `\clearpage` if not using `twoside` mode) before you start with `\chapter{Introduction}` just like you did before `\tableofcontents` (using `\newpage`). This will flush all content up to that point and start a new page and the appropriate page numbering will follow.

Without more detail, the document structure should resemble:

```
% Contents %
\cleardoublepage% \clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

% List of Figures %
\listoffigures

% List of Tables %
\listoftables

% Introduction %
\cleardoublepage% \clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Depending on whether you use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or not, you may have to add some modifications to the above.

Comment: Thank you so much - this really helped! I'm still in the early stages of getting to grips with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`, `\setcounter{page}{1}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` commands after the introduction chapter starts, in this way:

```
% Contents %
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

% List of Figures %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{List of Figures}

% List of Tables %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} 
\chapter{List of Tables}

% Introduction %
\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out! This is great advice :)